# Cleaning up system env of conda packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I forgot to activate a new conda environment,I created before, so I started installing the packages. Now my system is littered with packages. How do I clean this up? I only want my conda packages to be in the base environment and the ones I create.
I checked
[How to clean local python environment of conda installs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225890/how-to-clean-local-python-environment-of-conda-installs)
but that is of no help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have pip installed? If so, run pip freeze and save the output to a file. Review the file, make sure there are no packages listed that you DO NOT WANT to remove. Now, write a script to read in that file to a list, only keeping the package names. Have python loop over that list and uninstall each entry.